# Generate PDF File With Image

Tags: pdf-generation, jpeg

I am trying to generate a PDF file manually, line by line.
I want to put an image into it but it doesn't work out to just put in the image stream, there also is a compressed stream at the beginning of the file, which seems to be necessary.

Sample PDF File with image:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 2048 1365]/Resources<</XObject 6 0 R>>/Contents 2  0 R/ArtBox[0 0 2048 1365]/CropBox[0 0 2048 1365]/Parent 8 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj

<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 53>>
stream

THE STREAM THAT I AM TALKING ABOUT

endstream
endobj 

3 0 obj
<</D[1 0 R/FitH 1370.000]/S/GoTo>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Filter/DCTDecode/Width 2048/Height 1365/Length 623547/BitsPerComponent 8>>
stream

...

JPEG DATA HERE

...

endstream
endobj

...
```

So, what is that stream and how to create it? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at object 1:

```
1 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 2048 1365]/Resources<</XObject 6 0 R>>/Contents 2  0 R/ArtBox[0 0 2048 1365]/CropBox[0 0 2048 1365]/Parent 8 0 R>>
endobj
```

It represents a page (`/Type/Page`) and references object 2 as its contents (`/Contents 2  0 R`). So your mystery stream contains the description of what is drawn on the page modeled in object 1!

Content streams are not necessarily compressed but due to the verbosity of the PDF content description instructions they usually can be compressed quite well.

In such a stream there can be quite a variety of instructions for setting states (colors, transformations, transparency, ...) and drawing text/bitmaps/vector graphics as determined by those settings.

In your case the contents stream should at least contain something like

```
2048 0 0 1365 0 0 cm
/Im0 Do
```

**Im0** being the name you associate with your image resource in object 6.

---

That all being said, instead of using pure trial and error, you should simply read the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its not pure trial and error, I'm comparing many PDF files and I have a PHP script, which helps a bit. Honestly, the PDF reference documentation is too hard to understand for me, I need code samples to better understand stuff.

Comment: It is a good idea to look at real-life PDFs. But as soon as one thinks to find a pattern there, one should look it up in the specification. It might be a red herring after all...